# How come with Catalyst::Controller::REST I get an error about content-type

Tags: perl, rest, dispatcher, catalyst

How come with `Catalyst::Controller::REST` I keep getting this in dialog

```
[info] Could not find a serializer for an empty content-type
```

And, this to the browser

> Cannot find a Content-Type supported by your client.

I have this line in my package..

```
__PACKAGE__->config(default => 'text/yaml');
```

I also have installed `YAML::Syck` and `URI::Find` [per the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Controller::REST)

```
package Sampcat::Controller::Client::Holiday;

__PACKAGE__->config(default => 'text/yaml');                   

BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller::REST' }                 

sub holiday :Chained('../client') :Args :ActionClass('REST') {}

sub holiday_GET {                                              
  my ( $self, $c )  = @_;                                      
  $self->status_ok( $c, entity => {                            
    'foobar' => 1                                              
  } );                                                         
  $c->stash->{body} = "foo";                                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this bug on [RT for more information](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=106403&results=55e0bf35a5cf9265b09bc2c20b3109e8)

;tldr.. Change

```
__PACKAGE__->config(default => 'text/yaml');
```

to

```
__PACKAGE__->config(default => 'text/x-json');
```

for the time being.

Comment: You might want to[ add a git issue](https://github.com/perl-catalyst/Catalyst-Action-REST/issues) and ping jnap in #catalyst. He's pretty active at the moment.